# How do you remove a class from elements inside a component in React.JS when clicking outside given component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu, navigation

I am trying to emulate a behavior similar to clicking on the overlay when a Modal popup is open. When clicking outside the sidenav component, I want to close all elements that are currently in a `flyout` mode.

I have a multi-tier nested navigation menu that is stored in its own component, `Sidebar`. I have the following piece of code that handles `clicks` that occur outside the `Sidebar` component:

```js
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    ...
    handleClick = (e) => {
      if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
        return;
      }
  
      console.log('outside');
    };
  
    componentDidMount() {
      window.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick, false);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      window.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClick, false);
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <div
              ref={node => this.node = node}
              className="sidebar"
              data-color={this.props.bgColor}
              data-active-color={this.props.activeColor}
          >
          {renderSideBar()}
          </div>
      );
    }
    ...
}
```

This part works fine - but when the flyout menus get displayed on clicking a parent menu option, I would like it to close -any- flyout menus that are currently opened.

```
-|
 |
 - Menu Item 1
  |
  |-option 1 (currently open)
  |-option 2
 - Menu Item 2
  | 
  |-option 1 (closed)
  |-option 2 (closed, clicked to expand - this is when it should close [Menu Item 1/Option 1]
```

The menu items are generated using `<li>` tags when mapping the data object containing the menu structure.

Is there a way to basically select all registered objects that have the class of 'collapse' / aria-expanded="true" and remove it? Similar to how `jQuery` would select dom elements and manipulate them.

I know that this is not the premise in which React works, it is just an example of the behavior I want to emulate.

Comment: What is a flyout menu? Presumably it is a child descendent of your `SideBar` component. Have you tried passing a prop value down to your menu items to close?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Check if this example helps you: https://codesandbox.io/s/public-close-accordion-elements-using-ref-cobmn. It uses [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to close child elements.

Comment: @macborowy can you submit this as an answer? It was able to help me resolve the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to modify the DOM subtree from another component. To achive your goal you can use [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Using `ref` is helpful when you want to access [HtmlElement API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) directly - in my example I use [`animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate). Please, read [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) as it describes more of `ref` use cases.

Below is the simple example of [animating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) `<Sidebar/>` shrinking when user clicks on `<Content />`.

```js
const { useRef } = React;

function Main() {
  const sidebar = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    sidebar.current.hide();
  };

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Sidebar ref={sidebar} />
      <Content onClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
}

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { visible: true };
    this.show = this.show.bind(this);
    this.sidebar = React.createRef(null);
  }

  show() {
    if (!this.state.visible) {
      this.sidebar.current.animate(
        { flex: [1, 2], "background-color": ["teal", "red"] },
        300
      );
      this.setState({ visible: true });
    }
  }

  hide() {
    if (this.state.visible) {
      this.sidebar.current.animate(
        { flex: [2, 1], "background-color": ["red", "teal"] },
        300
      );
      this.setState({ visible: false });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.sidebar}
        className={this.state.visible ? "sidebar--visible" : "sidebar"}
        onClick={this.show}
      >
        Sidebar
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Content({ onClick }) {
  return (
    <div className="content" onClick={onClick}>
      Content
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: teal;
}

.sidebar--visible {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  flex: 7;
  background-color: beige;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```